# Bottomsheet height got fixed and content inside it gets scrollable. I want my Bottomsheet height according to it's content

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I worked in another project where I implemented same code and it works well there but in my new project it doesn't work.

somehow my bottomsheet height got fixed and content of it which is inflated into it gets scrollable. I want bottom sheet height should be adjusted according to its content and not scrollable.
What and where, Am I doing wrong please suggest me.
My BaseBottomsheetDialogFragment xml to show Dialog from BottomSheet is as :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">


</FrameLayout>
```

and I inflate this Framelayout with AddFriendConfirmationFragment xml and this is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bottomsheet_bg"
android:padding="5dp">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_10dp"
            android:text="Add Friend to your List?"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/name_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="Full Name"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title_2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_line_bg"
                    android:hint="Enter Full Name"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/error1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/transaction_failed"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                    android:visibility="gone" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/error1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="Nick Name"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nick_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_line_bg"
                android:digits="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
                android:hint="Enter Nick Name"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error1_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/transaction_failed"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="Mobile Number"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_line_bg"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/transaction_failed"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                android:visibility="visible" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_error"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/transaction_failed"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_error"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/proceed_bar"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/big_button_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="16dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripplebg_viewscircle"
    android:padding="6dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/closesvgnormal"

    />
```

and my code to show bottom sheet is:

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;

                FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                //BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);


                if (bottomSheet != null) {

                    final BottomSheetBehavior behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                    // behaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

                    behaviour.addBottomSheetCallback(new LockableBottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                            if (newState == CustomBottomSheetBehaviour.STATE_DRAGGING) {

                                behaviour.setState(CustomBottomSheetBehaviour.STATE_EXPANDED);

                            } else if (newState == CustomBottomSheetBehaviour.STATE_EXPANDED) {

                                // setStatusBarColor("#000000");


                                if (behaviour instanceof LockableBottomSheetBehavior) {
                                    ((LockableBottomSheetBehavior) behaviour).setLocked(true);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

                            bottomSheet.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                    int action = event.getAction();
                                    switch (action) {
                                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                            return false;
                                        default:
                                            return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    });

                }

            }

        });
        if (from == Constants.ADD_FRIEND_CONFIRMATION || from == Constants.DELETE_EXPENSE) {

            dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        // TODO do the "back pressed" work here

                        if (from == Constants.ADD_FRIEND_CONFIRMATION) {

                            AddFriendConfirmationFragment addFriendConfirmationFragment = (AddFriendConfirmationFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("addFriendConfirmationFragment");

                            if (addFriendConfirmationFragment != null) {

                                if (addFriendConfirmationFragment.status == 1) {

                                    Log.d("upisdk", "onkeybackpressed cancel ADD_FRIEND_CONFIRMATION");

                                    dismissDialog();
                                    return true;

                                }
                            }
                        } 
                        return false;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
        return dialog;
   }
```

Comment: Both "it's" and "its" in the title, really covering all the bases, huh?

Comment: @DavidConrad can you please help me what i am doing wrong over here?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I found a work around as in my styles.xml under tag <style name="bottomsheet_dialog" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog"> an item tag was added <item name="android:maxHeight">300dp</item>. I just removed it and it started working. But what should I do if this maxHeight for the bottomsheet is needed for other purpose where fixed height required (may be device size).